# dotnet --version gives "the folder [/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders"

Tags: .net, macos, ssl, terminal, command

When I run `dotnet --version` in Terminal on my Mac it gives an error:

> A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders

It can find the `dotnet` executable, but `--version` is not working:

```
anasmahdi@Anass-Air ~ % dotnet

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
anasmahdi@Anass-Air ~ % dotnet --version
A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders
anasmahdi@Anass-Air ~ %
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, on an M1 Mac. Because `/usr/local/share/dotnet/` was inside my `$PATH` (I still don't know why), it was looking at the wrong `dotnet` executable:

[image]

After running

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

as described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22910#issuecomment-986187662) and restarting the Terminal, the problem went away.

A few weeks ago, I switched to

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

as described [in another comment](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22910#issuecomment-1034404909).